# Solr group count by field not working

Tags: solr

Given this field definition

```
<field name="mtype" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

and corresponding type

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
```

I need to obtain a count grouped by mtype. This is the query i expected to work:

```
`/solr/select?q=deleted:False&wt=json&indent=true&fl=id,name&group=true&group.field=mtype`
```

but i get an ungrouped list of results:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":2,"params":{"fl":"id,name","q":"deleted:false","wt":"json"}},"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[{"name":"hello1","id":"80e9756d-8dd3-4cd0-b7c4-edebb9561f89"},{"name":"hello2","id":"80e9756d-8dd3-4cd0-b7c4-edebb9561f899"}]}}
```

According to the example here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping it should work.. any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks